# How to prevent specialization of a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces

The compiler doesn't complain when I do this ;-)

```
// Myfile.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace std
{

template<> class vector<int>
{
public:
    vector ()
    {
        std::cout << "Happy Halloween !!!\n";
    }
};

}
```

Is there any way to prevent this kind of undesirable specialization of a class/function template?

#### --EDIT--

I just used std:: as an example. What I'm looking for is a way to prevent this from happening to any template class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I tried this on gcc4.9.2 with -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra and it complies with no warnings

Comment: @nav Just because the compiler doesn't issue a warning or error doesn't mean it's OK to do something.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I concur in this instance. The OP's code is obviously absurd. But one *can* specialize a `std` template so long as it specializes dependent to a user-defined type, the specialization fulfills the requirements of the original template behavior, and the template is not prohibited from specialization by the standard. Last I checked anyway. It wouldn't be the first time I misread the standard.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? You obviously can't stop every kind of bogus use case--e.g. people can also cast away const, you can't stop them there--so why are you concerned in particular about this particular case?

Comment: Preventing people from doing stupid things often comes at the cost of preventing them from doing good things as well. There are different approaches, but personally I would worry more about documenting what the templates rely on (so people can use them correctly) instead of trying to imagine what bad things people might try.

Comment: The only working way to prevent template specialization looks like this: `// Don't specialize this template, or else. -- The boss`.

Comment: to be honest I don't get what the template is doing, or is inteded to do.

Comment: @Arne: Looks like this question was edited by someone yesterday; I've rolled it back to the original post. The question should be clear now.

Comment: The use of std:: was deliberate; I used it to emphasize how badly someone could tamper with a framework that's considered rock-solid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) can not be specialized and has the behaviour you need for class templates.

```
template<class T>
struct my_class_implementation_which_should_not_be_used_directly
{
    // impl
};


template<class T>
using my_class = my_class_implementation_which_should_not_be_used_directly<T>;
```

In addition you should document that specialising `my_class_implementation_which_should_not_be_used_directly` results in undefined behavior. Now your libraries user can not specialize `my_class` accidentally and is warned about the class with the ugly name directly.

Comment: Accepting this one for the explicit mention of 'alias template'

Answer (score 12):

What you do is specialize a standard library type inside a standard namespace.

Except for a few documented *customization points* (std::swap, std::hash<>) or specificly constrained specializations for User Defined Types (e.g. `MySmartPtr<T>`) this is against the specification and the result is undefined behaviour.

---

**Edit**: There is no mandatory diagnostic for this kind of rule violation.

To make it marginally harder for clients of your library to mess things up, you can do this trick:

```
namespace Public {


    namespace Hidden { // DON'T TOUCH THESE!
        template <typename> struct MyType { };
    }

    using Hidden::MyType;

}
```

Now, attempting to specialize `MyType<>` in namespace `Hidden` will fail.

Comment: Thanks sehe.. But how about a class which I write? Is there any way from someone messing it up? (Please see my edit to the question)

Comment: @nav added an idea to make it harder. You can't ***["protect against Machiavelli"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm)*** though (Loosely quoting Herb Sutter)

Comment: Most standard library templates can be specialized for user-defined types ([namespace.std]/p1: "A program may add a template  specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."), though only a few are commonly specialized this way.

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) is a rough list of `template` specialization rules within `std`.  It looks, at first glance, to be reasonable.  The general rule is "allowed, except", and this lists the extra requirements.  Note that the OP's specialization is illegal for 2 reasons (`int`, and the resulting `vector` fails to pass the requirements of a `vector`)

Comment: @T.C. You're both quite right. I do remember now. I'll add the other exceptions

Comment: Offering bounty to the most voted answer. To be honest, I wanted to share the bounty between the 3 top answers, unfortunately SO doesn't let us do that :(

Comment: Thanks @nav! It's a pleasant surprise. I wasn't aware of any pending bounties

Answer (score 8):

No, the C++ language does not provide a general mechanism by which you can say "don't allow specializations of this template".

But it may not matter. For any instantiation that your code uses already, a user provided specialization will violate the one definition rule and their program may blow up in a fireball.

If you *aren't* using the instantiation in your library then what they do doesn't matter.

This is one of the cases where in C++ you simply can't prevent your user from shooting themself in the foot and if they choose to do so the responsibility is on them.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You can prevent specializations of your templates with enable_if in C++11. This is impractical though.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<
  typename real_t,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_floating_point<real_t>::value
  >::type
>
struct check_t;

template<
  typename real_t,
  typename = typename
    std::enable_if<
      std::is_floating_point<real_t>::value,
      check_t<real_t>
    >::type
>
class vec_t
{

};

#if 1
template<>
class vec_t<int> {};

template<>
class vec_t<int,check_t<int>> {};
#endif

void test()
{
    vec_t<float> vecf;
    vec_t<int> veci;
}
```

[link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/366b2ed145d924a5)

```
main.cpp:26:16: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

Comment: No, that prevents any *instantiations* if the supplied type is not floating point. I can still specialize it, e.g. [code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3cd5cc3150176c6).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prevent such behavior is through coding standards and code review.

You cannot force the compiler into an error in this case (other than using workarounds like those suggested in other answers), because that behavior is actually allowed by the language, although it's real usefulness can be questioned.
The matter is - it is very possible that you want/need to provide a generic behavior for multiple types (hence the use of templates) but you need to provide a specific implementation for some of the allowed types (notably std::string)

A quick & dirty example (it's a function, but the same could apply to classes) could be the following:

```
template<typename TData> TData GetData(std::string argument)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    TData retVal;
    stream.str(argument);
    stream >> retVal;
    return retVal;
}
```

However this is going to fail with std::string, as the >> operator would stop after the first blank space. So you could provide a dedicated specialization.

```
template<> std::string GetData(std::string argument)
{
    return argument;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are a few ways to go about this. You can declare specific specializations without defining them. eg:

```
template<> struct MyStruct<int>;
```

That way, if someone tries to instantiate with an int, they would get this specialization and it won't compile because there is n definition. Then you can write a simple macro to do this for all the types you don't want a specialization for.

For the inverse of this, make the definition empty:

```
template<typename T> struct MyStruct{};
```

Then define the specific types you plan to support:

```
template<> struct MyStruct<int> {...};
template<> struct MyStruct<std::string> {...};
//etc...
```

Comment: If someone wants to use the normal class (without specialization) for `int`, then also it won't compile. Moreover how many specialization should he declare ?

Comment: The premise of your answer is wrong. `template<> struct MyStruct<int>;` is _just_ a declaration. There's still _nothing_ preventing another developer from providing a definition for it.

Comment: @iammilind That's why I provided two different solutions - one being the negative/inverse of the other.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes, you're right. I guess what I should have said is to provide an empty definition so that it can't be defined again due to ODR and it also won't work in real use when clients of the templated class tries to actually reference the members that are defined in the default or provided specializations.